# Can we backup and restore custom webparts and service application to development by taking farm backup?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, backup, restore

I want to clone production environment to development, only farm backup and restore will backup service application and custom webparts ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to create a backup of your site and then restore it.

### For Backup

```
 Backup-SPSite -Identity http://Constoso -Path "c:\backup\YourSiteBackup.bak"
```

### For Restore

```
 Restore-SPSite -Identity http://DestinationServer -Path "c:\backup\YourSiteBackup.bak"
```

But you will need to be careful while while restoring the webparts.

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a6301886-a9cb-46e1-963a-1fbd0df0bf2b/custom-web-part-not-registered-after-sharepoint-restore?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) maybe of some help: